# ng-repeat not displaying data from localStorage

Tags: angularjs

In my Controller:

By clicking on an element, the information is given to tabNameStore.
The data is displayed in html by name

```
     $scope.openTab = function($event){

     //Checks for doubles
     if($scope.tabNameStore.length>0){
         for(var i=0; i<$scope.tabNameStore.length; i++){                
             if($scope.tabNameStore[i].id == $event.currentTarget.id){
                 console.log("Already open");
                return;
             }
         }
     }

     //Saves name, ID and number
     $scope.tabNameStore[count] = ({name: $event.currentTarget.innerHTML, 
 id: $event.currentTarget.id, num: count++});

     //Tries to get item by id
     var local = localStorage.getItem($event.currentTarget.id);

     //If not stored in local, it does so
     if (local == null){
      localStorage.setItem($event.currentTarget.innerHTML, 
$scope.tabNameStore[count-1].name);
      localStorage.setItem($event.currentTarget.id, 
$scope.tabNameStore[count-1].id);
      console.log("null");
    } else{
        console.log("not null");
        return;
    }

 }
```

Save the data from localStorage back in tabNameStore

```
     $window.onload = function() {       
     var archive = [];
     archive = allStorage();
     count = 0;

         for(var i=0; i<archive.length/2; i++){ 
             if(archive[i] != null){
                 $scope.tabNameStore[count] = ({name: archive[i], id: 
         archive[i+archive.length/2], num: count++});
             }
         } 
 }
```

Getting all data from localStorage

```
     function allStorage() {
     var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);          // Gibt alle Schlüssel zurück
     var archive = [];

    for (var i=0; i< keys.length; i++) {
        archive.push(keys[i]);
    }
     return archive;
 }
```

The HTML is:

```
   <article id="default">

    <div id="heading">
            <a href="###" class="tab" id="desktop" >Desktop</a>
            <a href="###" class="tab" id="" data-ng-repeat="y in 
    tabNameStore" data-ng-click="" >{{y.name}}</a>  
    </div>

    <div class="gridly toggle" id="Desktop">
        <div class="brick small" draggable="true" data-letters=" 
          {{x.name[0]}}" id="{{x.id}}" data-ng-repeat="x in storage | 
          orderBy: '-name'" data-ng-click="openTab($event)">
            {{x.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
    </article>
```

After reloading the page and getting the data from localStorage it's still not displayed, even if the array is filled. Just if I click again on one of my elements (openTab function), all elements stored in localStorage are displayed at once.

Comment: Post your html as well

Comment: @VickyGill Added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

By adding a `$scope.$apply` around the part that reloads the array:

```
     ....
     $scope.$apply(function(){
         for(var i=0; i<archive.length/2; i++){ 
             if(archive[i] != null){
                 $scope.tabNameStore[count] = ({name: archive[i], id: 
                 archive[i+archive.length/2], num: count++});
             }
         }
     });
     ....
```

Like this the updated array is set up for angularjs after reloading.